# how to make an application that make a copy of its database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I'm making a C# application that uses a local database created with SQL Server

But when I create the database I used a connection to the local database with a file path on my local hard disk, and when I install the program on my computer it works correctly, because it is connected to the same database on my hard disk.

But when I publish my application and install it on a different computer it can't connect to the database because the connection in the C# code uses the same file path in my computer.

So now I create another database in `C:\Program Files\Application Folder` and make a connection in C# code with the same database. When I install the application on another computer how can I make a copy of database with the tables, because when I make a copy on the database it doesn't contain the tables.

Please help if you can.

Comment: Use SQL to create a schema of the database.  You can then create new database in other computers by using the schema.  if you want to include data then you can de-attach the database.  Make a copy of the mdf file.  Then re-attach the database to original SQL Server.  SQL server doesn't allow you to copy the mdf file while it is still attached to the server.

Comment: Your answer is was so helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can connect the database in the local network. And if you want to copy the database, you can attach your database file in the SQL server in the computer that you want to apply.

Answer (score 0):

I would save all the creation scripts.  When you create a new table, I would save the script that was generated.  I would then tell the program to launch the scripts when it installs.